# Not able to get default select values in ts file

Tags: angular, ionic3

how to get values of dynamically selected input in typescript

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let specs of spec;let i = index">
   <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>
        {{specs.title}}
     </ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" value="{{specs.t_value}}" 
                [(ngModel)]="specification[i]" name="specification"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that for dynamic fields

```
   <form #myForm="ngForm">
         <ion-list *ngFor="let specs of spec;let i = index">
               <ion-item>
                  <ion-label stacked>
                    {{specs.title}}
                 </ion-label>
                 <ion-input type="text"[(ngModel)]="specs.t_value"   #value="ngModel" name="specification[{{i}}]"></ion-input>
                 </ion-item>
             </ion-list>
<button ion-button block   color="primary" (click)="insert(myForm)">Save</button>
</form>
```